# How to prevent out of memory errors when loading large images for cropping on Android?

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory

My Android app is trying to load large photos (Facebook profile photos) and let the user crop them. This works fine for most users. A small percentage of users get Out of memory errors.

Normally, when handling large images, I use Glide. Glide handles resizing the photo to the actually visible size.

In this case, I'm using an image cropping library (com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper). The user has to be able to zoom into the photo. The library has to return me the cropped photo for use. So, the actual full resolution has to be loaded.

Because the current behavior works well for almost all users, I'm thinking of having special code to detect if an out of memory error would happen. If it would happen, it must be a low end phone. Then, the down sampling would happen, but only enough to make the phone work (and still be able to zoom/crop).

How can I detect if an out of memory error would happen loading the image?

How can I anticipate what the largest possible resolution is that the image can be without an out of memory error?

Would android:largeHeap="true" fix the problem? (I don't have the particular phones that are encountering the error. Crashlytics is reporting it for a small number of users.)

Should I calculate the available heap size and anticipated image size to decide if downsampling is required?

```
final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
final long usedMemInMB=(runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / 1048576L;
final long maxHeapSizeInMB=runtime.maxMemory() / 1048576L;
final long availHeapSizeInMB = maxHeapSizeInMB - usedMemInMB;
```

(Found code)

Comment: I think you can only try to put your code on which you are getting exception in throwable block and in this block you can show message to a user for low memory(out of memory exception)

Answer (score 0):

try this this works for me :-
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" use this in Manifiest

and in gradle add this line:-

android 
{
 ....
 dexOptions 
{
    // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
}